# All possible matrices of binary data on condition that row sums equals 1

Tags: r, matrix, binary, permutation

I am trying to generate matrices of `m*n` elements with binary data on the condition that the sum of the rows must equal 1.

For example, all the possible 2*2 matrices of binary data on condition that the row sums equal 1 are:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    1    0

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    0

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    1
```

Can anyone help out with some neat code to achieve such an output? Or is there a function that can help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward approach involves generating all vectors of length *n* containing *n - 1* zeros and *1* one. This is reduced to all permutations of the multiset `{0, 0, ... ,0, 1}`. Let's say that there are *K* such permutations.

Once we have all of these, we generate the permutations of *K* with repetition of size *m*, where *m* is the desired number of rows. We use each of these results to subset the permutations of the zeros and ones.

Below, we have implemented this using the library `RcppAlgos` (disclosure: I am the author). The first part (i.e. generating permutations of multisets) is accomplished using the `freqs` parameter. The second part is accomplished using the `FUN` parameter, which allows one to pass arbitrary functions that act on each permutation.

```
library(RcppAlgos)

binMat <- function(m, n, row_sum = 1) {
    perms <- if (n == row_sum) {
        permuteGeneral(1, n, repetition = TRUE)
    } else {
        permuteGeneral(0:1, n, freqs = c(n - row_sum, row_sum))
    }
    
    permuteGeneral(nrow(perms), m, repetition = TRUE, FUN = function(x) {
        perms[x, ]
    })
}
```

Note, in the above that one can generate matrices with different row sums using the `row_sum` parameter.

Here is an example:

```
binMat(3, 2)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    1
[3,]    0    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    1
[3,]    1    0

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    0
[3,]    0    1

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    0
[3,]    1    0

[[5]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    1
[3,]    0    1

[[6]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    1
[3,]    1    0

[[7]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    1    0
[3,]    0    1

[[8]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    1    0
[3,]    1    0
```

It's efficient as well:

```
system.time(testMany <- binMat(7, 7))
 user  system elapsed 
1.936   0.062   1.999

testMany[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
[7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1

length(testMany)
[1] 823543
```

Answer (score 2):

With `base R` this can be a solution,

```
#    m : number of columns
#    n : number of rows

 my_fun <- function(m,n) {

    a <- max(m,n)

    mat <- diag(1, a, a)

    x <- 1:nrow(mat)

    y <- paste0(rep("x",n),collapse=",")

    exp <- paste0("expand.grid(",y,")")
    all_com <- eval(parse(text=exp ))


    out <- lapply(1:nrow(all_com),function(x){

    if(m>n) {
        mat[as.numeric(all_com[x,]),]


    }else{

      mat <- mat[as.numeric(all_com[x,]),][,1:m]
      mat <- mat[rowSums(mat)==1,]

    }
            })

    

    out <- out[lapply(out,length) == m*n]

      return(unique(out))

}
my_fun(2,2)
```

gives,

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    1    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    0

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    0    1

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    0    1
```

Comment: I think you can get rid of the `eval` code. I got it to work by doing the following: `y <- rep(list(x), n)` and `all_com <- expand.grid(y)`.